# solr search transliteration from latin to native language characters

Tags: solr

I use apache solr engine.
How I can give the ability to the users to make transliterated searches?
For example, in case they type in latin letters, these should be transliterated and searched in their native language letters.
like latin to greek, or latin to russian. the same as google is doing.

Is the transliteration happening and then the searching takes place?
Or there is also a transliterated index?

How I can implement something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, at the moment transliteration is not application(task) for solr.

> How I can implement something like
>   that?

Probably I would transliterate the users input into the "solr letter type", before sending the input to solr.

> the same as google is doing.

You could use the google transliteration api: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/language/transliterate/overview.html

Comment: is there any other search engine that can do it? preferably an engine that cooperates with drupal. I would appreciate if it is possible to have some implementation guidelines. thanks

Comment: I know this module. but does it provide transliteration?

Comment: The target for the drupal "solr-plugin" is an easy way to combine php scripts with solr. This doesn't add an transliteration feature for solr. What you can do is the following: ask an transliteration API (for example the google api) or use an PHP based transliteration like this one: http://drupal.org/project/transliteration . After transliteration: perform an solr search with the result of this transliteration by using the drupal-solr-plugin.

Comment: so you mean there is no ready solution, but it must be developed. right?